# innerHTML not working on td element

Tags: innerhtml

I am making one of the project and the problem I am facing is in innerHTML. I am trying to append the edited value using innerHTML but it is not working. Please help me on how to do this. This is my javascript code for editing the value. How can I append the value without reloading the page?

```
$("#save1").click(function(){
    var edit = $("#eretail").val();

     $.ajax({
         url:"ajax.php",
         type:"post",
         data:{"type":"editretailer","curr_id":$("#selected_id").val(),"name":edit},
         success:function(data){

          $("#consoled").modal('hide');

      });  
   }     
});
```

And the edit button and the value which is shown to user come from the code:

```
<tbody id="retail">             
            <?php
                while($rowService = mysqli_fetch_array($retailer)){


            ?>
             <tr class="gradeU">
                <td><?php echo $rowService['retailer_name']; ?></td>

               <td>
                <a href="#" class="tooltips editType" id="<?php echo $rowService['retailer_id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#consoled"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>

                <a href="addRetailer.php?type=delete&id=<?php echo $rowService['retailer_id'];?>" class="tooltips" title="Delete" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Remove?');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></td>
             </tr>
            <?php } ?>
          </tbody>
```

Comment: Please explain it properly so that we can help you in better way. What element you want to add? and which node is you are picking as parent?

Comment: Where you are appending innerHtml in your code ?

Comment: I don't know how to append that.But i want to append in 1st td element where the retailer name is shown to user

Answer (score 0):

You can use append function of jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Let say from your code

```
$( "#retail" ).append( "<tr><td><?php echo $rowService['retailer_name']; ?></td></tr>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Append to first td of your table as

```
 $('.gradeU  td:first-child').append("<p> hi</p>")
```